# Polymorphic pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, polymorphism

I am struggling with Polymorphism in C++. I have 2 classes, `Hero` and `MainPlayer`. `Hero` is base class and `MainPlayer` is derived from `Hero`. In `Hero` I have some variables and methodes, and `MainPlayer` has some additional variables and methods. I am trying to create polymorphic pointer just like:

```
Hero *player = new MainPlayer(constructor);
```

and then with the player I can only access the methods from `Hero` class, otherwise there is a compile error. I would like to ask if it is possible
to use `MainPlayer` methods and variables via this polymorphic pointer: `player`.

My code:

```
class Hero
{
public:
    Hero();
    virtual void fun() = 0;
private:
    int a, b;
};

class MainPlayer:
public Hero
{   
public:
    MainPlayer();
    void fun();
    void fun2();
private:
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    Hero *player = new MainPlayer(constructor);
    player->fun(); // works
    player->fun2(); //doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is best understood when presented, not described.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: A bit about terminology: a pointer is a pointer; there is no such thing as a "polymorphic pointer". A pointer can point at an object of a polymorphic type, which is what you're looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the pointer to the base class `Hero` you can only call functions and access members of the `Hero` class.

This has the important exception, that a virtual function of the base class that is overridden in the derived class (with the same signature as described in the derived class `MainPlayer`), it will call to the implementation of the derived class (even if it doesn't contains the keyword `override`).

Finally a pointer to `Hero` created from `MainPlayer`, can be cast back to a pointer of `MainPlayer`, and then you can call functions and access members from `MainPlayer`, like in the following example:

```
Hero * h2 = new MainPlayer();
MainPlayer * h3 = dynamic_cast<MainPlayer*>(h2); 

if (h3 != nullptr)
{
    h3->fun2();
}

delete h2;
```

Finally don't forget to delete your allocated pointer

---

Edit:

The `override` specifier, while not necessary, help you to ensure that you are indeed overriding a function from the base class. If the base class doesn't declare a virtual function with the same signature, the program will not compile. Here is a simple example for this concept:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo();
    void bar();
};

struct B : A
{
    void foo() const override; // Error: B::foo does not override A::foo
                               // (signature mismatch)
    void foo() override; // OK: B::foo overrides A::foo
    void bar() override; // Error: A::bar is not virtual
};
```

Comment: Worth an edit to point out what the `override` keyword really does and why you should use it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify that it's the overriding of a virtual function that explains the "important exception", not just the signature (i.e. if the base class function would not be virtual, it would call the base class version and not the derived one despite the same signature).  I agree with @user4581301 : it would be nice to explain the benefits of using `override` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Here is an example. h2 is pointing to Hero however it is using method from MainPlayer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Hero
{
public:
    virtual std::string whoAmI() const { return "The Hero"; }
};

class MainPlayer : public Hero
{
public:
    std::string whoAmI() const override { return "The Main Player"; }
};

int main()
{

    Hero h1;
    std::cout << h1.whoAmI() << std::endl;
    Hero *h2 = new MainPlayer;
    std::cout << h2->whoAmI() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
The Hero
The Main Player
```

Comment: Yeah but I would like use a method of derived class that name hasn't been declared in base class.

Comment: @Hunteerq can't be done. `Hero` only knows `Hero` stuff. It can't know about future extensions.

Answer (score 2):

When a `MainPlayer` is accessed through a pointer to a `Hero` the only exposed interface is that of `Hero`, and the compiler can only take advantage of functionality known to `Hero`.

How to get around this (in order of my personal preference):

Avoid interacting with a `MainPlayer` as a `Hero` in situations where `MainPlayer`'s additional functionality is required. `MainPlayer` attacks and takes damage (more or less thanks to the possibility of an override) just like everyone else, but if only `MainPlayer` can `SwingFromChandelier`, only `MainPlayer` should be offered the opportunity to do so. Most of the time in this case `MainPlayer` will already be available as a `MainPlayer`.

Abstract away the need to expose additional functions. For example, perhaps `MainPlayer::fun` can call `MainPlayer::fun2` to do extra `MainPlayer` stuff. `MainPlayer`'s override of `Hero::Attack` could call the `BerserkRampage` specialty attack function, removing the need to expose `BerserkRampage` to anyone.

`Hero`s interface may be under-specified. Consider expanding `Hero` with additional virtual functions.

`dynamic_cast` `Hero *` to `MainPlayer *`, verify that the result is not  `nullptr`, and invoke `MainPlayer` functionality on the newly-minted `MainPlayer *`